# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute while using absolute imports

Tags: python, circular-dependency

```
[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z] _ ERROR collecting path/to/file/tests/test.py _

[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z] path/to/file/tests/test.py:12: in <module>

[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z]     import path.to.file.tests.utils as utils

[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z] path/to/file/tests/utils.py:9: in <module>

[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z]     from path.to.file.full import run

[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z] path/to/file/run.py:39: in <module>

[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z]     import path.to.file.compute

[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z] path/to/file/compute.py:33: in <module>

[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z]     import path.to.file.sim as sim

[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z] path/to/file/sim.py:13: in <module>

[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z]     import path.to.file.compute as compute

[2023-02-21T18:51:30.894Z] E   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compute'
```

I'm running into this error when running a unit test at my work's codebase. I can't run this unit test locally easily so I'm having a hard time debugging it. I believe this error is typical of circular dependencies. There is a circular dependency right now that we plan to change in the near future; however, here I am using absolute imports, so I'm wondering why the circular dependency is still occurring?

I checked some other unit tests that ran locally that also involved importing the circular dependencies, and those didn't result in the error.

Comment: does it work if you use `from path.to.file import compute`?

Comment: @ti7 Pretty sure it won't. I ran a local unit test with the original version of the code which used relative imports and it didn't work due to the circular dependency hence why I changed it to absolute imports. Let me paste the full error message as I'm not sure if it's helpful